# How to create vector of structs with fields that all implement a specific trait?

Tags: generics, vector, struct, rust, traits

I am looking for ways to create a `Vec` of structs that have fields implementing a specific trait, more specifically the following struct:

```rust
struct Animation<T: Add> {
    channel: TypeId,// channel/component to animate
    path: String, // string
    from: T, // T is a type that implements the ADD trait ie : can be either float or vec2, vec4, vec4 etc
    to: T, // T is a type that implements the ADD trait ie : can be either float or vec2, vec4, vec4 etc , same as from
    duration: u64,
    easing: String,
    repeat: i16
}
```

I am still new to Rust so sorry if this is obvious

- How would you use `Box<Animation>` for dynamic dispatch in this case?
- defining an enum that has a variant for each type (`f32`, `vec3`) works but seems very verbose.

Comment: I don't think you can really do it. You will need the actual types and `Animation<u64>` type is different from `Animation<u32>` for example. Maybe what you want is to actually have an `Animated` trait, and then you could have a `Vec<Box<dyn Animated>>`?

Comment: Netwave is correct: fields are not something you can abstract over. Instead, create a new trait.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot ! I split the struct up into homogeneous ones, works fine now.